# I was messing with Visual Studio Code and now all terminals open with (base) environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda

As the title says I was messing with Visual Studio Code  while I was checking the debugging functionality.

I obviously did something wrong because since then every new terminal I open, both on VSC and Ubuntu terminal opens with (base) environment

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you have run `conda init`, which adds an entry to your `.bashrc` file to automatically activate the base environment whenever you start a bash terminal.

If you want to undo this change completely, you can run:

```
conda init --reverse
```

However, this will mean that you can't run `conda activate`, for example.

If you just want to prevent conda from activating the base environment when you start your shell session, you can run:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

This will create a `.condarc` file in your home directory, with an entry of `auto_activate_base: false`. This will override any conda defaults.

Comment: conda config --set auto_activate_base false worked perfect, thank you very much for your time

Comment: Still the environments auto activate when I open a new terminal in visual code studio, any ideas ?